# Node Sequelize with Mysql order by, need 0 values to be last

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Here I'm trying to order the result using a filed order_no, the default value for order_no is 0. I have to sort the values to get the desired output like 1,2,3,0,0,0. I tried the below options in findAll() in sequelize but not working it is returning 0 values first.

```
let options = {
  attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT',
                Sequelize.col('user_id')),
                'user_id'],
               'order_no'],
  raw: true,
  where: {},
  limit: limit,
  offset: offset,
  order: [[Sequelize.fn('isnull',
           Sequelize.col('order_no'))],
          [Sequelize.literal('order_no'),
           'ASC']]
};
```

Comment: something like this? `[Sequelize.literal('\`order_no\` = 0, \`order_no\`')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IS_NULL` and `IF` functions to achieve such sorting:

```js
order: [Sequelize.fn('IS_NULL',
          Sequelize.fn('IF', 
           Sequelize.literal('order_no=0'), 
           null, 
           Sequelize.col('order_no')
          )
         ),
         'order_no'
          ]
```